# Automation tool similar to Sikuli

Tags: automation, sikuli

I really like the feature in Sikuli that allows you to select a screenshot to click and specify where within that screenshot to click. For example when there are multiple buttons that look the same, just taking a screenshot of the button itself won't cut it because Sikuli can't differentiate.

Some other automation tools don't allow you to select where you want the mouse to click within a screenshot, or it is difficult to specify where you want the mouse to click.

So my question is, is there another software tool that has this feature that Sikuli has? The reason I'm looking for something else is because I don't want to rely on image recognition completely. I was hoping to use pywinauto with Sikuli to do some of the automation, but that isn't possible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problems with using Sikuli are. Perhaps there is a way to overcome some of them without using other tools. Generally speaking, probably you won't be able to have the best of both worlds. Sikuli's biggest strength is in allowing you to interact with application that do not provide an API. On the other hand, it might be somewhat unreliable in some instances.

Comment: It's the unreliability that I'm trying to get around by minimizing my use of Sikuli. I have done some automation in Python using pywinauto.application to interact with objects but ran into the issue of objects not existing for some of what I want to click on, so Sikuli was the solution for that. What I want to do is still use Python whenever I can and use Sikuli image recognition only for clicking buttons, etc., where I can't use Python. Does that explain my problem better?

Comment: Which OS'ses do you need? Propriety allowed? If windows-only freeware AutoIt may help, though it is very much outside the Python world.

Comment: Right now just Windows and yes proprietary allowed. I'm looking into anything I can at this point. I'd prefer to stick to Python if possible but that's not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least one: [eggPlant](http://www.testplant.com) by TestPlant.

It is an automation tool using image recognition, and

> You can search part of the screen by setting the SearchRectangle global property.

References:
http://www.testplant.com
http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/using/epf-finding-images.htm#Working

---

For Python integration [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com) would be nice, and it does have nifty image recognition functions where you can have multiple image parts working together.
Not exactly what you are asking but it just might be of use.

References:
http://www.getautoma.com
http://www.getautoma.com/features/image_recognition

---

The odds are a bit longer but possibly [AutoIt](http://www.getautoma.com) can help you as well. It interfaces with the standard Windows GUI objects and has the benefits of being both very stable and quite easy to use. It has a small tool you can use to show the properties of the screen object you want to access. No learning curve to speak of, however no image recognition or real integration to Python either.

Reference:
https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: Both, eggPlant and Automa are non-free. There are plenty of paid automation frameworks.

Comment: @Eugene S, OP says propriety allowed. I'd love to see any free visual test tools with the (sub)region function though.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that part and deleted that from my comment but probably too late. Anyway, I am not sure what you mean by "subregion function"?

Comment: @Eugene S, region is what Sikuli uses to specify where within that screen-shot to click

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. Didn't you say that you'd love to see that in a free tool? So here it is

Comment: @Eugene S, Sikuli is one of very few free image recognition based test tools, and the only one having the region function that I know of. I'd love to be mistaken in this.

Comment: I know that Sikuli has that function, that's what I like about it, but I want to access objects as much as possible using Python in my Sikuli scripts and then resort to using screenshots when necessary. I've been using pywinauto for gui automation in Python but you can't use pywinauto in Sikuli so I thought I'd try looking for alternative tools. However, Sikuli is free so it'll probably win because it's not bad, just not ideal for me.

Comment: @sushimama, can you clarify what you mean by "you can't use pywinauto in Sikuli"? I thought you can invoke Sikuli as a python script.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGEX0dz_f_w&t=23s

Comment: Can you just run sikuli for the portions of the automation you need, and then use pywinauto for the rest of the automation?

Answer (score 0):

We are using now gehrmann/PyGUIBot (python and free): https://pyguibot.wordpress.com/

Has a command line interface and GUI, records screencasts, with simple graphical programming language. Good for GUI-unittests or user interaction scripting.

Never used it on Windows, only on Ubuntu or Debian, but it looks like a cross-platform tool.